# What is this way of simplifying $\prod ^{n}_{i=1} x_i^k$ correct? I want the K out.

Tags: products, algebra-precalculus

What is the correct way of simplifying $\prod^{n}_{i=1} x_i^k$ ?

I tried getting out the k to have :
$$ (\prod^{n}_{i=1} x_i)^{kn} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: $1^2\times 2^2\times 3^2\times 4^2 = (1\times 2\times 3\times 4)^2 \neq (1\times 2\times 3\times 4)^{2\times 4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. It is a matter of reordering things:

$$
a_1^k \dots a_p^k = a_1 \dots a_1 \times \dots \times a_p \dots a_p = (a_1 \times \dots \times a_p ) \times \dots \times (a_1 \times \dots \times a_p ) = (a_1 \times \dots \times a_p )^k
$$

So, $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^k = (\prod_{i=1}^n x_i)^k$.